# Samsung Vibrant not showing up on ADB device list WIN7

Tags: android, debugging, adb, drivers

I have a Samsung Galaxy Vibrant phone running android 2.3.7 CyanogenMod 7 ROM. I used to be able to debug on the device through ADB but since installing CM7, my device doesn't show up on the devices list. Also, when I connect the device, i get a message saying "Device driver software was NOT installed successfully".
I am running Windows 7 32bit.

Answer (score 0):

If your device driver is not installed properly, it won't showup. Uninstall the driver and install again, make sure driver you are installing is supported on Windows 7.

Comment: I uninstalled the drivers and re-installed, doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I think they are not supported. You may need contact samsung support.